# Dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 freezing after few seconds of inactivity

Tags: boot, dual-boot, drivers

I recently dual-booted Ubuntu and windows.

Now what is happening with me is whenever I leave my screen inactive for about 1-2 mins it freezes.

I can't move the cursor or do anything. It's happening with ubuntu only windows is running fine.

The only option left is to force shutdown and start again.

I have to do this every time.

[Following is the list of drivers I am currently using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zA8su.png)

Please provide me a solution for this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

After a "sudden shutdown", aka "system crash", and reboot, the terminal  command `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` will show you the end of the previous boot's log's. If there is no hint there, suspect power/ overheating.

Read `man journalctl` to see how to extract information from the logs.

You can find how I make use of `journalctl` easier at `https://askubuntu.com/users/25618/waltinator`.

Answer (score 0):

System "freezes" are often caused by running too many, too large programs and running out of available memory. Use `free` to see if you have swap space, read `man mkswap swapon fstab` to create some. Swap space must be contiguous. use `mkswap` or `fallocate`, not `dd`. Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV. If you don't plan to hibernate your system, you can have less than 1.0 × RAM.

Comment: Thanks man I think it worked. It didn't freeze this time. I will wait for 1 more day then I'II update if the problem persists.